# Unable to access data/misc folder contents in root mode

Tags: android, root, superuser

I have a rooted device running `MarshMallow`. I have integrated Chainfire's library [Library](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) in my code. I get the superuser prompt and granted the permission. After that I am trying to get the folders inside /data/misc/ but it returns me null. I have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission also in manifest and in App->Permissions have granted the same.
What I have tried so far ..

1. Checked /data/misc/ folder in ES File Explorer. It does have folders.
2. From cmd, ran 
   adb shell

   su

   cd /data/misc/

   ls

Was able to see the folders in cmd.

Can anyone please help how to solve this?

Code :

```
private final static String ROOT_DIR = "/data/misc/";
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Let's do some SU stuff
        suAvailable = Shell.SU.available();
        if (suAvailable) {
            Log.d("TAG", "SU there");
            //List<String> output = Shell.SU.run("mount -o rw,remount /");
            //Log.d("TAG","Output ="+output); // empty
             File file = new File(ROOT_DIR);
           if (file.exists()) {
               Log.d("TAG", "File exists"+ file.getAbsolutePath()+ file.isDirectory());
               File file1[] = file.listFiles(); // RETURNS NULL HERE
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is log response?

Comment: File exists/data/misc true

Comment: File[] filesArray = file.listFiles() would be better?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference..

Comment: You got error? This is common way to list files in a directory.

Comment: On printing Log.d("TAG", "Files ="+file.listFiles) gives me : Files =null

Comment: You cannot log File Array. Log this : `String.valueOf(file.listFiles().length)`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array . I get this if I use length.